# OPENSSL error after fresh install of Gcloud SDK

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-shell

Whenever I try to do anything that uses the internet at all it gives me the following error code:
`OPENSSL_Uplink(00007FFB8BB09B50,08): no OPENSSL_Applink`

The only other people that I could find that experienced this issue and resolved it are experiencing this within their own programming project but I can't apply their solutions since they are all just changing the code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.